# React why does adding key to component instance mess up date

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have a React data table component which I am adding to a parent component and which needs a key, like so:

```
<DataTable
  key={Math.random()}
  twoId={twoId}
  reviseTableData={reviseTableData}             
/>
```

Within the `DataTable` component, I have an `onClick` function which is successfully using `setState`. Here is a condensed version of the component code:

```
export default class DataTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selected: [],
      checkSelected: 0
    }
  }

  onRowSelect = (row, isSelected, e) => {
    if (isSelected) {
      this.state.selected.push(row.device)
      this.setState({checkSelected: this.state.checkSelected + 1},           
        function () {
          console.log('');
        });
    } else {
    var newArray = this.state.selected.filter(function(s) { return s !== row.device });
    this.setState({checkSelected: this.state.checkSelected - 1, selected: newArray}, 
      function () {
        console.log('')
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const selectRowProp = {
      mode: 'checkbox',
      customComponent: this.customMultiSelect,
      clickToSelect: true,
      onSelect: this.onRowSelect,
      onSelectAll: this.onSelectAll,
      syncClick: this.syncClick
    };

    const { selected, checkSelcted } = this.state

    return(
      <div>
        <BootstrapTable data={ this.state.tableData } selectRow={ selectRowProp } height='285' striped hover condensed
          tableHeaderClass='custom-select-header-class' tableBodyClass='custom-select-body-class' ref="table">
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='device' isKey dataSort={ true }>Host Name</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='device_type' dataSort={ true }>Device Type</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='sync_time' dataSort={ true }>Last Sync Time</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='sync_status' dataSort={ true }>Status</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
      </div>                    
    )
  }
}
```

In another part of this component I also have a function which is performing a .map function on the `this.state.selected` after it has been added to or subtracted from via the code above.

This all works perfectly when the component has no key added.

I `console.log` and everything works great and the `state.selected` maps correctly.

However, when I add the `DataTable` component to the parent component and insert the key as shown above, the function stops working because the `this.state.selected` shows as a blank array no matter how many items I have pushed in to it.

When I perform the `onRowSelect` function and `console.log` I can see that the item is successfully pushed to the state, but when I `console.log` the state from below render the state continues to be empty.

Again, this only occurs if I added the key to the component when I insert it into the parent component.

I'm guessing this is some kind of `bind(this)` issue but don't know how to solve. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: its happening because of the `key` value, each time you are assigning a random value and react will create a new instance of of `DateTable` component. assign same value like `key={'table-component'}`, it will work properly. if you not rendering the component in loop then you can skip the key part.

Comment: check this [sample snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/62830zpvxk) you will get the idea. each time you click button, `componentDidMount` will be called, means new react will create new instance.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mayank Shukla! I'm going to try your suggestions.